# Auto-increment Id based on composite primary key

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

*Note: Using Sql Azure & Entity Framework 6*

Say I have the following table of a store's invoices (there are multiple stores in the DB)...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Invoice] (
    [InvoiceId] INTEGER NOT NULL,
    [StoreId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Invoice] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([InvoiceId] ASC, [StoreId] ASC)
);
```

Ideally, I would like the InvoiceId to increment consecutively for each StoreId rather than independent of each store...

```
InvoiceId | StoreId
-------------------
1         | 'A'
2         | 'A'
3         | 'A'
1         | 'B'
2         | 'B'
```

**Question:** What is the best way to get the `[InvoiceId]` to increment based on the `[StoreId]`?

Possible options:

a) Ideally a `[InvoiceId] INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY_BASED_ON([StoreId])` parameter of some kind would be really helpful, but I doubt this exists...

b) A way to set the default from the return of a function based on another column? (AFAIK, you can't reference another column in a default)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[NextInvoiceId]
(
    @storeId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @nextId INT;
    SELECT @nextId = MAX([InvoiceId])+1 FROM [Invoice] WHERE [StoreId] = @storeId;
    IF (@nextId IS NULL)
        RETURN 1;

    RETURN @nextId;
END

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Invoice] (
    [InvoiceId] INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT NextInvoiceId([StoreId]),
    [StoreId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Invoice] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([InvoiceId] ASC, [StoreId] ASC)
);
```

c) A way to handle this in Entity Framework (code first w/o migration) using `DbContext.SaveChangesAsync` override or by setting a custom insert query?

*Note: I realize I could do it with a stored procedure to insert the invoice, but I'd prefer avoid that unless its the only option.*

Comment: Trying to roll your own identity like that is going to cause you some serious problems. Concurrency will bite you at some point. If you are using 2012+ a sequence is great way to deal with this type of thing. The real question I have is why do you want to do this? Your table has a clustered index defined which includes a guid...this will cause massive index fragmentation unless you continuously defrag it. Why can't you just use an identity?

Comment: For invoice IDs a store wants to see a list of concurrent values. If they get a list of invoices "1, 2, 4", then they'll be calling my support line asking what happened to "3"? Additionally, I'd prefer them not know how many invoices my website has processed across all stores, which they would be able to know if I used an Identity.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Sequences. If you can provide an example that'd be very helpful.

Comment: Don't display the identity to them and then they have no idea. If you use a sequence you would need a seperate sequence for every store. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx

Comment: There's a difference between an `InvoiceID` that your database uses for data integrity and an `InvoiceNumber` that your users should see and use to reference which invoice they're looking at. Keep the two things very separate - they have a totally different purpose.

Comment: Very true regarding InvoiceId & InvoiceNumber. Regardless if it is a PK or not I still have the same problem, don't I?

Comment: No, you dont. If `InvoiceId` is always incrementing selecting the `InvoiceNumber` is a case of "Row Number over InvoiceId". I'll put together an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should stick to an auto-incrementing integer primary key, this is much simpler than dealing with a composite primary key especially when relating things back to an Invoice.

In order to generate an InvoiceNumber for the sake of a user, which increments per-store, you can use a [`ROW_NUMBER` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx) partitioned by `StoreId` and ordered by your auto-incrementing primary key.

This is demonstrated with the example below:

```
WITH TestData(InvoiceId, StoreId) AS
(
    SELECT 1,'A'
    UNION SELECT 2,'A'
    UNION SELECT 3,'A'
    UNION SELECT 4,'B'
    UNION SELECT 5,'B'
)
Select InvoiceId,
        StoreId,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY StoreId ORDER BY InvoiceId) AS InvoiceNumber
FROM TestData
```

Result:

```
InvoiceId | StoreId | InvoiceNumber
1         | A       | 1  
2         | A       | 2  
3         | A       | 3  
4         | B       | 1  
5         | B       | 2
```

Comment: Thanks @Jamiec. Could this cause invoice numbers to change if the database were migrated or backup\restored?

Comment: Ah, nevermind... not with the ORDER BY InvoiceId. I'll give this a try!

Comment: I played around with this, but I couldn't get it to work nicely with Entity Framework without creating a separate View or Stored Procedure. Instead I stumbled into the solution in the below answer. I'd be curious to hear your thoughts on it...

Comment: @jt000 I would have used a view with this in it and have EF read from that view rather than the table itself.

Comment: The only reason I'm hesitant to go with your answer is because I'm concerned about not having the invoice number saved in the database where it could somehow get altered... Is there a way that this could be saved as a column directly in [TestData] in your example?

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with the answer provided by @Jamiec in my solution I instead decided to go the TRIGGER route in order to persist the invoice number and better work with Entity Framework. Additionally, since `ROW_NUMBER` doesn't work in an INSERT (AFAIK) I am instead using `MAX([InvoiceNumber])+1`.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Invoice] (
    [InvoiceId] INTEGER NOT NULL,
    [StoreId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [InvoiceNumber] INTEGER NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Invoice] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([InvoiceId] ASC)
);

CREATE TRIGGER TGR_InvoiceNumber 
    ON [Invoice]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO [Invoice] ([InvoiceId], [StoreId], [InvoiceNumber])
       SELECT [InvoiceId], 
              [StoreId], 
              ISNULL((SELECT MAX([InvoiceNumber]) + 1 FROM [Invoice] AS inv2 WHERE inv2.[StoreId] = inv1.[StoreId]), 1)
       FROM inserted as inv1;
END;
```

This allows me to set up my EF class like:

```
public class Invoice
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }

    public Guid StoreId { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public int InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How do you deal with concurrency? If two inserts are concurrent they will both get the same InvoiceNumber?

Comment: Would " WITH (UPDLOCK, READPAST)" take care of this? Additionally a unique constraint would prevent insertion (though, the user would get an odd error in this case)