# primary key increments based on another key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i am developing an accounting system for multiple factories in laravel. I have a bill no which auto increments and is primary key. what i want is to have a separate bill no. for each factory. i.e if a factory A created bill with id 1, its next bill should have id 2 instead of some other id such as 3,4 as the case when id 2 has been occupied by bill from factory B.
so i want

```
bill_id  factory_id
   1        A
   1        B
   2        B
   3        B
   2        A
```

instead of

```
bill_id  factory_id
   1        A
   2        B
   3        B
   4        B
   5        A
```

I have searched a lot but couldn't find a solution. I think this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27946892/auto-increment-id-based-on-composite-primary-key)  is the solution but can anyone explain it more and also how to implement it in laravel ?

Comment: `AUTO_INCREMENT` simply does not work like this. You have to do it manually.

Comment: have you checked the solution given in the link ? I need something like that in laravel.

Answer (score 0):

TRY:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE factory_id='A' ORDER BY bill_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

This will return the last id of the specific factory, from then on you can perform INSERT statement with increment. Note that **bill_id** should not be primary.

Comment: but the last id returned will be a number containing the number of bills of all factories. but i want to only get the number of bills of a specific factory including the bills deleted. i.e there may be repetition in bills number for different factories but bill numbers must be unique for a factory.